# Show a linear map is self adjoint

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that if $v_1,...,v_n$ is an orthonormal basis of an inner product space V and $s_1,...,s_n$ are real scalars, then the linear map $T:V→V$ defined by
$$
T(v) = s_1〈v,v_1〉v_1 + ... + s_n〈v,v_n〉v_n
$$
is self-adjoint.

I know that v1,...,vn are a list of orthonormal vectors that are also a basis of V. v1,...,vn is also linearly independent. I have a feeling that Axler 7.13 "Every eigenvalue of a self-adjoint operator is real" will have to do with solving this proof, but I don't know where to start or how to connect the dots.

Comment: The adjoint of a linear map is defined by the condition: for all $v,w \in V$, $\langle Tv , w\rangle = \langle v , T^*w\rangle$. There's a unique linear map $T^*$ satisfying this condition. Thus you're essentially being asked: does this condition hold if we plug in $T$ for $T^*$?

Comment: I would suggest breaking this up into components. If you define $T_i(v) = \langle v, v_i \rangle v_i$ for each $i=1, \ldots n$, can you show that $T_i$ is self-adjoint? That is, can you show $\langle T_i v, w \rangle = \langle v, T_i w \rangle$ for all $v, w$? You can then use properties of the adjoint to show that sums and real multiples of self-adjoint maps are self-adjoint.

Comment: I do not know whether the underlying field of $V$ is $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. Assume $V$ is Euclidean. If you let $v_i=(0,\cdots,1\cdots,0)$ with the $i-th$ coordinate $1$ and others $0$, then the matrix of $T$ is $diag\{s_1,\cdots,s_n \}$. which satisfies $TT^{T}=T^{T}T$